# calling a javascript function without an element

Tags: javascript, html

I know it sounds a little bit strange, but I want a javascript function to be executed without being called by an `onclick()` `onblur()` `onchange` or anything like this.

My program is divided by many IFs. If a certain IF is executed, then I know that the javascript function should be executed, but there is not any HTML element that calls it.

This is in HTML.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of ifs? in php? Show us some code tis difficult to know what you are asking.

Comment: please post relevant javascript and html, this question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Could you explain how just calling a function isn't sufficient for your needs? That is, "if (x) { functionA(); } else { functionB(); }".

Comment: Please show us a HTML-snippet where you use `<IF>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do inline JavaScript, then you can do the following in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">myFunction();</script>
```

That will call the function without needing an event listener.

Comment: In this case, I want to call myFunction(); wich is in an external .js document. Can I call this function this way?

Comment: As long as you include your js file in the document BEFORE your function declaration. In your case, I would recommend making the script call in the `<head>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function anywhere you want to execute it. If it is part of html i.e inline script then make sure you have used script tags so that it will be treated as script by the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   functionName();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pub/sub pattern. JQuery has on built in

https://gist.github.com/1321768
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailedobserver